# Webpack-simple + vue-cli with SASS - Can't compile?

Tags: node.js, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-2, node-sass

I set up a simple project with vue-cli and webpack-simple using the default CLI settings and made sure that 'Y' was selected when asked whether I wanted to use SASS.

First, folder structure pic:

[image]

> I created a **`main.scss`** file in the `./src/scss` directory and
>   added the following simple scss syntax to the file:

```
$primary-color: rgb(173, 16, 16);
```

> Then, in my **App.vue** template, I have it like so:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>

h1, h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: $primary-color;
}

</style>
```

> In my **main.js** file, I made sure to import the main.scss file like
>   so:

```
import './scss/main.scss'
```

When running `npm run dev`, I get the following compiling error:

Failed to compile.

```
./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-04c2046b","scoped":true,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
Module build failed: 
undefined
        ^
      Undefined variable: "$primary-color".



    in D:\Users\medranns\Desktop\sasswebpack\src\App.vue (line 46, column 10)
 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-04c2046b","scoped":true,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue 4:14-316 13:3-17:5 14:22-324
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

> Here's what my **webpack.config.js** file looks like:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
            'scss': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ],
            'sass': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
            ]
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

> And **package.json** snippet:

```
"devDependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
"babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
"cross-env": "^5.0.5",
"css-loader": "^0.28.7",
"file-loader": "^1.1.4",
"node-sass": "^4.7.2",
"sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
"vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
"webpack": "^3.6.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
```

}

**I've followed the docs and still did a bit of searching around, but I am still unsure how to fix. Thanks for any leads!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i use scss in a vue project that is growing from `webpack-simple` boilerplate

```
vue-init webpack-simple test-scss
```

**Try below steps to setup scss in vue project**

After installing a basic setup using above command, install below npm packages

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass style-loader --save-dev
```

In `webpack.config.js` under rules array include below loaders

```
rules:[ 
...,
...,
{
   test: /\.scss$/,
   use: [{
       loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
   }, 
   {
       loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
   }, 
   {
       loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
   }]
}
]
```

**What was done upto this point?** Configurations that will enable compiler to convert scss to css are done.

Now import `.scss` into `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

import './style.scss';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

This is my folder structure

[image]

You are now ready to compile the object oriented css code in style.scss to CSS

**To use scss in component level scope** `lang="scss"` must be specified in `<style>` tag

```
App.vue
<style lang="scss">
    $override-color : green;

    div {
        color: $override-color;
    }
</style>
```

Refer [this manual](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) for more insights on this topic . Looking forward for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. Try to remove ?indentedSyntax in 'vue-loader':

```
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
      loaders: {
        'scss': [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
        'sass': [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
        ]
      }
      // other vue-loader options go here
    }
```

As a result it should look like this:

```
 test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
      loaders: {
        // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
        // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
        // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
        'scss': [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
        'sass': [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
      // other vue-loader options go here
```

Comment: „the right config“ looks exactly the same for both scss and sass? Or are you missing something? – Which Webpack Version is this, btw?